# Plot the life period of people listed in old testament

Tags: plotting

I have a question about how to use the plotting capabities of *Mathematica* to show the life span of people listed in Bible, Genesis Chapter 5 (from Adam to Noah) and Chapter 11 (from Shem to Abram).

The life period of each person is listed as follow.

Data from:

[Genesis Chapter 5 (from Adam to Noah)(NIV)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KvVj.png)

[Chapter 11 (from Shem to Abram)(NIV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011&version=NIV)

Name: First Life period, lefted life, total life

Adam: 0-130, 800, 930;

Seth: 0-105, 807, 912;

Enosh: 0-90, 815, 905;

Kenan: 0-70, 840, 910;

Mahalalel: 0-65, 830, 895;

Jared: 0-162, 800, 962;

Enoch: 0-65, 300, 365;

Methuselah: 0-187, 782, 969;

Lamech: 0-182, 595, 777;

Noah: 0-500, 450, 950;

Shem: 0-100, 500, 600;

Arphaxad: 0-35, 403, 438;

Shelah: 0-30, 430, 433;

Eber: 0-34, 430, 464;

Peleg: 0-30, 209, 239;

Reu: 0-32, 207, 239;

Serug: 0-30, 200, 230;

Nahor: 0-29, 119, 148;

Terah: 0-70, 137, 207;

---

[image: Like this one] @m_goldberg I just want to draw picture like the below ones.

Comment: I guass this picture's name should be Gantt chart. And I have two examples to show this: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/416871

Comment: Also this answer could be ok: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34421/how-to-create-a-combined-bar-plot-with-time-format

Comment: I don't see a clear question here. Can you edit your post to include a description of how you want the plot to look?

Comment: Shelah: 0-30, 430, 433; need to be corrected as: Shelah: 0-30, 430, 460

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Have you seen [`TimelinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimelinePlot.html)? (new in version 10.1)

Answer (score 2):

```
NumberLinePlot[{
  Interval[{0, 130}], 
  Interval[{130, 930}],(*1Adam*)
  {Interval[{130, 235}], 
   Interval[{235, 1042}]},(*2Seth*)
  {Interval[{235, 325}], 
   Interval[{325, 1140}]},(*3Enosh*)
  {Interval[{325, 395}], 
   Interval[{395, 1235}]},(*4Kenan*)
  {Interval[{395, 460}], 
   Interval[{460, 1290}]},(*5Mahalalel*)
  {Interval[{460, 622}], 
   Interval[{622, 1422}]},(*6Jared*)
  {Interval[{622, 687}], 
   Interval[{687, 987}]},(*7Enoch*)
  {Interval[{687, 874}], 
   Interval[{874, 1656}]},(*8Methuselah*)
  {Interval[{874, 1056}], 
   Interval[{1056, 1651}]},(*9Lamech*)
  {Interval[{1056, 1556}], 
   Interval[{1556, 2006}]},(*10Noah*)
  {Interval[{1556, 1656}], 
   Interval[{1656, 2156}]},(*11Shem*)
  {Interval[{1656, 1691}], 
   Interval[{1691, 2094}]},(*12Arphaxad*)
  {Interval[{1691, 1721}], 
   Interval[{1721, 2151}]},(*13Shelah*)
  {Interval[{1721, 1755}], 
   Interval[{1755, 2185}]},(*14Eber*)
  {Interval[{1755, 1785}], 
   Interval[{1785, 1994}]},(*15Peleg*)
  {Interval[{1785, 1817}], 
   Interval[{1817, 2024}]},(*16Reu*)
  {Interval[{1817, 1847}], 
   Interval[{1847, 2047}]},(*17Serug*)
  {Interval[{1847, 1876}], 
   Interval[{1876, 1995}]},(*18Nahor*)
  {Interval[{1876, 1946}], 
   Interval[{1946, 2083}]}(*19Terah*)
  }, 
 PlotLegends -> {"1Adam", "1Adam", "2Seth", "3Enosh", "4Kenan", 
   "5Mahalalel", "6Jared", "7Enoch", "8Methuselah", "9Lamech", 
   "10Noah", "11Shem", "12Arphaxad", "13Shelah", "14Eber", "15Peleg", 
   "16Reu", "17Serug", "18Nahor", "19Terah"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Black, Gray, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, 
   Brown, Orange, Pick, Purple, LightRed, LightGreen, LightBlue, 
   LightGray, LightCyan, LightMagenta, LightYellow, LightBrown}]
```